# How to install Segment on WordPress without a plugin

Tags: functions, wp-admin

I want to add Segment to my WordPress site. I read the best way to do this is to edit functions.php and use wp_enqueue_scripts

I've replaced my tracking code with "test"

This is the segment code:

```
<script>
!function(){var analytics=window.analytics=window.analytics||[];if(!analytics.initialize)if(analytics.invoked)window.console&&console.error&&console.error("Segment snippet included twice.");else{analytics.invoked=!0;analytics.methods=["trackSubmit","trackClick","trackLink","trackForm","pageview","identify","reset","group","track","ready","alias","debug","page","once","off","on"];analytics.factory=function(t){return function(){var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);e.unshift(t);analytics.push(e);return analytics}};for(var t=0;t<analytics.methods.length;t++){var e=analytics.methods[t];analytics[e]=analytics.factory(e)}analytics.load=function(t){var e=document.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript";e.async=!0;e.src=("https:"===document.location.protocol?"https://":"http://")+"cdn.segment.com/analytics.js/v1/"+t+"/analytics.min.js";var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(e,n)};analytics.SNIPPET_VERSION="4.0.0";
analytics.load("TEST");
analytics.page();
}}();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add that code to a js in your theme folder (or child theme if you're using it). for this example I named the script "analytics.js" and put it in a directory called "js" in my child theme folder.

Now register and enqueue the file by placing this code in your functions.php

```
function wpse_load_script()
{
    // Register the script like this:
    wp_register_script( 'analytics-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/analytics.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

    // You can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'analytics-script' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_load_script' );
```

Comment: I'm doing something wrong. I created a file on sublime, added the code and called it segment.js.

I then added the file to the child theme directory under a new folder called js. I added your code to functions.php and changed the script name to segment.js

Comment: Make sure that you don't have <script> at the top or </script> at the bottom?

Comment: I did have that at the top and the bottom. I removed it


function wpse_load_script()

{

    // Register the script like this:

    wp_register_script( 'analytics-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/segment.js', array( 'jquery' ) );


    // You can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'analytics-script' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_load_script' );

Comment: You removed it from the .js file, right?  Is the script being found when you debug or are you getting a different error.

Comment: Yes, I removed it from the .js file - https://pastebin.com/BDjFeZXV

Nothing is showing up in debugger and it is saying no recent data

Comment: Try this:  https://pastebin.com/h5RsRdYA

Comment: good.  Can you mark as answered?